# Clutch doesn't lift up immediately when I lift up my leg

Tags: clutch

I have a [10+ years old manual car](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perodua_Kancil), still under a pretty good condition I would say.

Recently, I feel its clutch, doesn't perform quite well as expected.

Usually, when I lift up my leg to release clutch, the clutch suppose to lift up immediately as well. I will feel like the clutch is "sticked" on your foot.

Recently, when I lift up my leg to release clutch initially, I don't feel like the clutch is being lift up immediately. My feeling is that, after rising up my foot says for 5cm, only the clutch will start to rise up.

I was wondering, what could goes wrong with my clutch? As far as I could remember, I just changed my clutch system less than 2 years ago, it works well all the time.

Will applying some oil, or lubricant on the "clutch outer joint" help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is not actually **clutch sticking**, but I guess it will sooner come to it, where your clutch would literally get stuck to the floor and won't lift up.

Here are a few things that might be causing this:

1. **Broken clutch cable**. (Stretched cable might also be a reason)
2. **Hydraulics line may have some air**.
3. **Your clutch master cylinder being low on fluid**.

P.S - Am not sure about Kancil's clutch type though, therefore mentioned both cases.
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now we don't know what car it is. Anyway the are two types of clutch release: hydraulic and cable pull. I would say, you have the second one. The problem is, that your cable do not release the clutch as good as early, because of corrosion or some technical effects. Look at the cable-gearbox-connection, how is that releasing. Maybe I am wrong and you have hydraulic one. Then maybe vent a system will help.